# set session value as a databse value using mysqli_stmt_bind_result

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to set the session value to equal my customer ref from the database however I can't seem to get it to work properly. The echo is printing a 0 instead of the correct customer ref

Here is my code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {
$loginEmail = $_POST['loginEmail'];
$loginPassword = md5($_POST['loginPassword']);
// the db should only be queried if both email and password are filled in
if (empty($loginEmail) || empty($loginPassword)) {
    $Error = "Email and Password can't be left blank";
}
else {
    $sql = "SELECT customerRef FROM customer WHERE Email=? AND Password=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $loginEmail, $loginPassword);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id); 


        echo $id;
        if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 2) { // this is normally 1 i just changed it to 2 so i wouldnt be redirected everytime
            // sets the session values
            $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
            $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['loginEmail'];
            header("Location: homepage.php");
            die();
        }
        else {
            $Error = "Username or password is incorrect";
        }
    }
}
// Close statement
$stmt->close();
// Close connection
$conn->close();
} //end of sign in isset
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: From your code above, at no point was your CustomerRef assigned to any session variable. Secondly, you need to verify that the email and password combination (using MD5 for the password) is valid with a record in your database. Thirdly, instead of using MD5 on password you can use the improved password hash function, which is more secure

Comment: @OPMat I know the customerRef hasn't  been assigned that's why I am asking for advice. I am verifying that the email and password exist with the prepared statement above. If I have time I will switch md5 for the password hash

Answer (score 1):

You haven't actually called `mysqli_stmt_fetch()` so nothing will have been stored into `$id`.

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php):

> When mysqli_stmt_fetch() is called to fetch data, the MySQL
>   client/server protocol places the data for the bound columns into the
>   specified variables var1, ....

So add

```
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
```

after your call to `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`.

Comment: @RubadubDub this should solve the issue, then you can assign id to a session variable